# How to use a CSV file to update all column values in a table?

Tags: bash, csv, sqlite

I wish to replace column values in a sqlite3 (Clementine) db table named `songs` using a CSV file I imported and named as a table `songsnew`.

The CSV file has three columns with headers that have fieldnames matching those in the target database.  The common column I want it to "index" to is `filename`.

Using SQLiteBrowser, I tried this SQL taken from another answer:

```
update songs
set lastplayed = (select songsnew.lastplayed
where songsnew.filename = songs.filename)
where
exists (
select *
from songsnew
where songsnew.filename = songs.filename
)
```

It did not work. The error message says:

```
no such column: songsnew.lastplayed: update songs
```

...which is odd because as I am typing that SQL into the SQLite database browser, it correctly identifies 'pops up' the column `filename` for the `songsnew` table.

Using SQLite3 and/or bash, can this be done only by importing the CSV as a table?  Which way is simplest and how is it done? I do not wish to manually update thousands of records one at a time.

As requested in the comments, here is first the schema `songs`:

```
CREATE TABLE `songs` (
    `title` TEXT,
    `album` TEXT,
    `artist`    TEXT,
    `albumartist`   TEXT,
    `composer`  TEXT,
    `track` INTEGER,
    `disc`  INTEGER,
    `bpm`   REAL,
    `year`  INTEGER,
    `genre` TEXT,
    `comment`   TEXT,
    `compilation`   INTEGER,
    `length`    INTEGER,
    `bitrate`   INTEGER,
    `samplerate`    INTEGER,
    `directory` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `filename`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `mtime` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `ctime` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `filesize`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `sampler`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `art_automatic` TEXT,
    `art_manual`    TEXT,
    `filetype`  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `playcount` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastplayed`    INTEGER,
    `rating`    INTEGER,
    `forced_compilation_on` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `forced_compilation_off`    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `effective_compilation` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `skipcount` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `score` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `beginning` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cue_path`  TEXT,
    `unavailable`   INTEGER DEFAULT '0',
    `effective_albumartist` TEXT,
    `etag`  TEXT,
    `performer` TEXT,
    `grouping`  TEXT
);
```

...and here is the schema for the CSV file songsnew after importing:

```
CREATE TABLE `songsnew` (
    `filename`  TEXT,
    `playcount` TEXT,
    `lastplayed`    TEXT
);
```

Comment: How did you get the data into SQLiteBrowser? If you have imported it, it's already there. Show the output of `.schema` in the `sqlite3` command-line shell.

Comment: OK - that has been added above.

Comment: The column is there. Did you import it into the same database?

Comment: Yes, the `songsnew` table is in the same database as `songs`.

Comment: Well, I figured out a somewhat crude way to do this using Excel (or LibreCalc). You have to write a line of bash script for each record updated. If you are updating two columns, `lastplayed` and `playcount` you can 'automate' the script-writing process using formulas.  For mine it was 13,000 rows each of which looks something like: `update songs set lastplayed = 1464776851, playcount = 9 where rowid = 13643;` Combine quoted text (use quotations for text and with "&" for cell references) and cell references in Excel, then copy all of the rows from Excel to a bash script for the SQLite3 commands

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more convenient way:

```
with delta(fn, pc, lp) as
(select a.filename, a.playcount, a.lastplayed from songsnew a )
update songs set 
     lastplayed = ifnull((select lp from delta where fn = filename), lastplayed),
     playcount  = ifnull((select pc from delta where fn = filename), playcount)
where filename in ( select fn from delta);
```

It uses

- a CTE to for getting around ambiguities,
  `with delta(fn, pc, lp) as ...`
- a construct to fill in values you might not have in songsnew,
  `ifnull(...)`
- a where-clause to speed up,
  (the ifnull construct would also prevent changes elsewhere, but be much slower)

You might want to increase songs.playcount by songsnew.playcount, in that case use
`playcount  = ifnull((select playcount+pc from delta where fn = filename), playcount)`.

On SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28